# XAMPP DocumentRoot when using a Different Drive

Tags: xampp, httpd.conf, drive, document-root, htdocs

I've changed my DocumentRoot and Directory to both point to D:/Docs/Websites/projectname in the httpd.conf file, but every time I go to localhost/index.php, it's like XAMPP doesn't even register that I've changed anything and redirects to localhost/XAMPP.

I've searched for about an hour with no luck, is it possible to have your working directory on another drive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved. Just forgot that you need to restart Apache after editing the httpd.conf file. Hope this helps anyone else.